# Create A New Order State

Tags: prestashop, state

I have created a new order state. I want that it works as a the "canceled order state". So I need to edit some code. Now, my new state decrease the stock and I need that the stock increase like as order_canceled.

I have added my new id order state (11) in OrderDetail.php in checkProductStock function, but it doesn't work, the stock is still decreasing. Any idea?

```
if($id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED') && $id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR') && $id_order_state !=11) {
    ... //not decrease the stock
    }
```

Comment: You have added `&& ... !=` (and ... is not) to your `if` statement. What are you going to achieve by it?

Comment: What? I dont understand your question. I want to create a ORDER STATUS CANCELED BANK WIRE. How can I do that???

Comment: I think you have an error in your `php` if statement you have posted here. Just revise it.

Comment: Only it is a if statement with 3 conditions if( A!= 0 && B!=0 && C!=0) { ...} I think that is not the problem.

Comment: You need to use `if (A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 0) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

To make your order state work the same way as "canceled order state", simply open classes/order/OrderHistory.php and look for $errorOrCanceledStatuses. Than add your id_order_state like this (in my case 28):

```
$errorOrCanceledStatuses = array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED'),28);
```

Save your modifed file to "override" folder and don't forget to delete cache/class_index.php